# En datatable, con laravel como puedo pasar información de manera correcta, cuando es mas de una consulta en el controlador?

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, datatables

Tengo en mi vista una tabla, que se ejecuta en un modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
                        <table class="display table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap"
                               style="width:100%" id="tableModal" name="tableModal">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>cant</th>
                                <th>codigo</th>
                                <th>referencia</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>enBa</th>
                                <th>valor</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

luego tengo un método en js que se ejecuta, después de presionar un botón, este captura las variables necesarias. y mediante ajax, hace un llamado al controlador, y este devuelve información.

```
 public function detallepedido(Request $request)
    {
       $idpedido = $request->idPedido;

        $productos = Producto::where('pedido', $idpedido)
        ->get();

         return Datatables($productos)->make(true);
    }
```

hasta ahí, no tengo problema.
este es mi codigo del ajax que me pinta la tabla.

```
var dataTable = $('#tableModal').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                scrollY: 400,
                scrollX: 500,
                order: [[0, "asc"]],
                ajax: {
                    url: "{{ route('detalle.pedido') }}",
                    data: {idPedido: idPedido}
                },
                columns: [
                    {data: 'cant', name: 'cant'},
                    {data: 'id_producto', name: 'id_producto'},
                    {data: 'referencia', name: 'referencia'},
                    {data: 'nombre', name: 'nombre'},
                    {data: 'emba', name: 'emba'},
                    {data: 'valor', name: 'valor'},
                ],
               
                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
            });
```

Pero ahora, necesito capturar en el controlador la información de campos de varias tablas de mi bd,
y no me sirve join, por que algunas tablas, no tienen llaves entre ellas.

He intentado, después de hacer las consultas, hacer algo como un array, y pasárselo a la datatable,
pero me marca error.

intenté en el controlador lo siquiente:

```
public function detallepedido(Request $request)
    {
        $idpedido = $request->idPedido;

        $pedido = Pedido::where('id_pedido', $idpedido)->first();
        $cliente = Cliente::where('codcli', $pedido->codcli)
        ->first();
        $detallepedido = DetallePedido::where('id_pedido', $idpedido)
        ->get();
              
        $data = array();
        foreach ($detallepedido as $pedido) {
                
            $producto= Producto::where('id_producto', $pedido->id_producto)->first();

            $data[] = array(
                'cant' => $pedido->id_pedido,
                'id_producto' => $pedido->id_producto,
                'referencia' =>  $producto->referencia_producto,
                'nombre' => $producto->descrip_producto,
                'emba' => $producto->precenta_producto,
                'valor' => $pedido->valor_producto,
            );
        }

        return Datatables($data)->make(true);

    }
```

pero me marca error, claramente por que seguro me esta pasando en un formato que no entiende.
como podria pasarle el dato que lo entienda, o como puedo modificar mi ajax de datatable, para que le de formato a mi tabla y me muestre la informacion! muchas gracias.

cuando me devuelve la informacion de manera correcta, me entrega algo tipo asi:

```
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":2,"recordsFiltered":2,"data":[{"id_detalle":123771,"id_pedido":4528,"id_producto":49359,"cantidad":2,"valor_producto":2000,"iva_producto":0,"total":4000},{"id_detalle":123772,"id_pedido":4528,"id_producto":49362,"cantidad":4,"valor_producto":422,"iva_producto":0,"total":1688}],"input":{"idPedido":"4528"}}
```

Cuando me devuelve los datos  "mal" me los devuelve tipo asi:

```
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":2,"recordsFiltered":2,"data":[{"cant":4528,"id_producto":49359,"referencia":"ABR030","nombre":"ABRAZADERA LARGA 30cm X 100 PQ 18045","emba":"PAQ-X100","valor":2000},{"cant":4528,"id_producto":49362,"referencia":"ADR1D8D","nombre":"ADAPTADOR DE ROSCA PLATA DE 10mm DERECHO A 8 mm DERECHO MIROK 123234","emba":"UND","valor":422}],"input":{"idPedido":"4528"}}}
```

yo no veo la diferencia en la manera que me devuelve el return de una a otra.
para que la tabla dejé de funcionar. :(
que podria hacer? gracias.

el mensaje de error que obtengo es:

DataTables warning: table id=tableModal - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

y no me muestra ningun dato

Comment: Este es el mensaje que obtengo

DataTables warning: table id=tableModal - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: No, no tiene ningun otro mensaje.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado el problema, al ver que estaban pasando las cadenas igual, y compararlas a detalle, me di cuenta que no podria ser un problema del datatable, si le estaba pasando la informacion de manera correcta.

al mirar mas a detalle, me di cuenta que una de las consultas era  ->first() y no ->get().
por lo tanto tengo que acceder a ellas de manera diferente.
asi que accedi de la siguiente manera y ya funciona.

```
            $data[] = array(
            'cant' => $pedido->id_pedido,
            'id_producto' => $pedido->id_producto,
            'referencia' =>  $producto['referencia_producto'],
            'nombre' => $producto['descrip_producto'],
            'emba' => $producto['precenta_producto'],
            'valor' => $pedido->valor_producto,
        );
```